# Filtering instanceId by sourceIP

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm building a Python Lambda where, every time a EC2 instance calls it, it should include this instance in an ELB target group. So my "logic" is, I have the IP from this instance because of the headers. If this IP, I can identify the InstanceID. With the InstanceID, I can add it to the target group.

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('elbv2')
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        
    internal_IP = {
        'body': event['requestContext']['identity']['sourceIp']
    }

    filters = [{
        'Name': 'private_ip_address', 
        'Values': [internal_IP],
    }]
    result_list = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
    instid=result_list['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']


    response = client.register_targets(
        TargetGroupArn='arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXX',
        Targets=[
            {
                'Id': instid
            },
        ]
    )
```

The problem is that I'm not able to use the "internal_IP" as a value in the filters. I get the error: "'int' object is not subscriptable". I made a lot of changes in the code to fix it, but no success...

The IP is returned when I run the code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   
    response = {
        'body': event['requestContext']['identity']['sourceIp']
    }
    return response
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `'Values': [internal_IP.body]` or simply `'Values': [event['requestContext']['identity']['sourceIp']]`

Comment: The `internal_IP` variable contains a _dictionary_, whereas the filter only wants the IP address. @Jarmod's suggestions should work.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod, it worked as expected!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @jarmod (thanks!) the working code is:

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('elbv2')
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

filters = [{
    'Name': 'private-ip-address', 
    'Values': [event['requestContext']['identity']['sourceIp']]
}]
result_list = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
instid=result_list['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']


response = client.register_targets(
    TargetGroupArn='arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:xxx',
    Targets=[
        {
            'Id': instid
##            'Port': 8443,
##            'AvailabilityZone': 'us-west-1'
        },
    ]
)


return {
'statusCode': 200,
'body': json.dumps('Success')
}
```